# Crystal reports - using value of current object in formula

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports, self-reference

I am creating a Crystal Report using c# and I have to replicate a simple formula in 320 different parameters but always with the same condition as follows:

```
if ({Precios.AhorroE1}[1] = '-') then crGreen else ( crRed )
```

Each object has a different name (in the example aboce, Precios.AhorroE1 but I have to make the SAME condition for 320 different objects.

I've been trying to find a way to refer to the object that is evaluating the formula but I couldn't find it. I would like to know if it is possible to do something similar to:

```
if ({currentobject}[1] = '-') then crGreen else ( crRed )
```

Where `currentobject` would be the object evaluating the formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For formulas that evaluate to *almost all* data types you can use the keyword `CurrentFieldValue` to format it. So if you had a formula that evaluated to a string, you could place it in the report and then set the color of its text the way you describe:

`if CurrentFieldValue='-' then crRed else crGreen`

Except formulas can never evaluate to an array so you can not use it in the way you're describing by indexing into the `CurrentFieldValue` as if it were one.

Comment: yeah. That did it. Either way the [1] I put there it's not because it is an array but because it's the way the Substring function is used. So in fact I'm taking the first char in the currentfieldvalue and cheking if it is '-' or not. It works!